# How to find out which i18n properties are not longer in use in vue js project vs code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

I have a vuejs project that uses i18n and I am trying to find out which properties are not longer required. I have a list of properties in a json file with over 1300 properties(not included in the project directory).

How can I find out whish properties from the json file are not being used in the project?

Comment: https://github.com/pixari/vue-i18n-extract

Comment: Thank you very much @M